# error: mismatched or outdated versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I got this error by using the diagnosticMVC Nuget package

*************************************Error******************************************************

ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly Information (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll)

Mismatched or outdated versions of ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET MVC Futures are loaded.

Loaded version of ASP.NET MVC is: ASP.NET MVC 4 RTM (4.0.20710.0)

Loaded version of ASP.NET MVC Futures is: Unknown version (4.0.20710.0)

A download for this version of ASP.NET MVC Futures is not available. Pre-release versions of the MVC Futures assembly are no longer available once that version of ASP.NET MVC has gone RTM.

Assembly version: Unknown version (4.0.20710.0) Full name: Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Code base: file:///C:/Users/kpindiprolu/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Mobility/Mobility/MobilityForms/MobilityForms/bin/Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DLL Deployment: bin-deployed

---

My code has a custom built navigation menu which uses Microsoft.web.MVC which I believe is the futures library. so, I can't remove the library.

can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Here's a hard lesson learned: never develop production code using futures. Since it's too late for that apparently, you can either go ahead and update to MVC5, which really shouldn't involve much if you're already on MVC4. The majority of the changes were added features. But, see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 before you dive in. Or, remove the dependency on futures, by refactoring your code so it's not needed.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes it'a very hard lesson and learned too late. But I want to  understand few things here. This code was developed by a guy who worked in my position before..he used MVC4Futures and developed it..when I got the code from him and deployed in my laptop it just worked fine...it never complained about this mismatch...I even deployed it in my local IIS and it just works fine...This problem comes when I move the build to the server?..can you explain why?..I never installed mvc4Futures on my machine , I just copied his packages and it worked..

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I would say this is Nuget's fault. There's a feature called "package restore", which allows you to pass along your project or solution without including the actual Nuget packages and then, once it's being built, any missing packages are pulled back down. This works great in most scenarios, but when and if one of those packages no longer exists (such as futures), it can't restore it, and the build suddenly fails. Most likely it was still available when you installed it locally, and was only removed later.

Comment: yes that explains it. Thank you , now I need to figure out what needs to be done. It looks like "LinkBuilder" is the class library that is being used from the futures. It currently looks like if I replace it with  any existing libraries from system.web.MVC , it might resolve my problem... IS there any library in the core MVC that you can think of which will replace my "LinkBuilder" Logic?